# How does Pinterest remember what pin I was looking at after installed the app on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, safari

I'll probably get hammered for making a question without code in it, but I didn't know how else to find an answer for it, and it is a programming question after all.

From what I've been researching, in order to communicate from a website to an app, you need URL-Schemes. But that doesn't work before the app is installed.

I found other questions about using cookies, but for that you need to actually open safari from the app, and again, you have to have the app installed in order to do that (plus, it seems as Apple is rejecting apps with this method).

But I noticed that Pinterest does it somehow.

Let's say I'm on Safari looking at something on Pinterest. I get a message saying "Open in Pinterest App".

I tap on that and I'm taken to the app store app where I can download Pinterest.

After installing Pinterest and opening the app, I'm taking automatically to the same pin that I was looking at on Safari.

**EDIT 1:**
These guys claim to do something similar.

https://blog.branch.io/introducing-the-first-universal-app-open-banner-that-deep-links-past-install/

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you log in to a user account?

Comment: It made me create an account on the app, but I didn't have an account on Safari

Answer (score 0):

I think it passes an info added on the URL scheme regarding that pin. The URL scheme will take you to the app store if the app is not installed and when you open the app, the app will parse the url scheme if there's data included on it like the pin id and will now redirect you to that pin.

Comment: The URL scheme doesn't take you to the store. If you just use the URL scheme, you get an alert saying "Cannot Open Page". So they are doing something else when you DON'T have the app installed

Comment: My bad, yeah it doesn't take you to the app store, because I have used url scheme on Facebook API that will take you to the store if the app is not installed. But I'm certain that they append the pin ID in the url scheme that's why when you installed the app it redirects you to that pin.